# For every graph $G$, prove that $\beta(G)\leq2\alpha'(G)$

Tags: graph-theory

For every graph $G$, prove that $\beta(G)\leq2\alpha'(G)$. ($\beta(G)$ is the minimum cardinality of a vertex cover, $\alpha'(G)$ is the number of edges in a maximum matching of $G$.)

I went in circles:

Consider a (connected) graph with $n$ vertices. Gallai's Theorem tells us $\alpha(G)+\beta(G)=n=\alpha'(G)+\beta'(G)$. So write $\beta(G)=\alpha'(G)-\alpha(G)+\beta'(G)\Rightarrow-\beta(G)=-\alpha'(G)+\alpha(G)-\beta'(G)$. Theorem 10.12 (just some theorem in our book) tells us $\beta(G)\geq\alpha'(G)$, so $-\alpha'(G)\geq-\beta(G)=-\alpha'(G)+\alpha(G)+-\beta'(G)$. $-\alpha'(G)\geq-\alpha'(G)+\alpha(G)-\beta'(G)$, and...

obviously I'm just going in circles, because the other half of Theorem 10.12 says $\beta'(G)\geq\alpha(G)$, which is what would fall out of my argument above...not helpful. So how do I go about doing this? The fact we are proving this for *any* graph leads me to believe I need to use some previously established inequalities here, and this "Theorem 10.12" is the only inequality that we've really done in this chapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point here is that if you take a maximum matching $M$ and look at the set $N$ of all vertices incident to edges in $M$, then $N$ is a vertex cover (as otherwise there is an edge with neither of its incident vertices in $N$. But then we could have added that edge to $M$ to form a bigger matching, contradicting the maximality of $M$).

So $N$ is a vertex cover of size $2\alpha^\prime(G)$, and so certainly $\beta(G)\leq 2\alpha^\prime(G)$ since $\beta(G)$ is the size of a smallest possible vertex cover.

Comment: Well, looks like I was going about it entirely wrong...