# When is $\beta(G)=2\alpha'(G)$ for a graph $G$?

Tags: graph-theory

From a question (see link) here at math stackexchange I saw that $\beta(G)\leq 2\alpha '(G)$ and I think I understand the proof. What I am not sure is when this inequality turns into an equality, i.e. for what graph $G$ is $\beta(G)=2\alpha'(G)$? Is there any such graph?

$\alpha'(G)$  is the number of edges in a maximum matching of G.

$\beta'(G)$ is the minimum cardinality of a vertex cover.

[For every graph $G$, prove that $\beta(G)\leq2\alpha'(G)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1050043/for-every-graph-g-prove-that-betag-leq2-alphag?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete graph $K_5$ on $5$ vertices is such an example. It has $\beta'(K_5)=4$ and $\alpha'(G)=2$.

[image]

In fact all disjoint unions of odd complete graphs are examples in which equality holds. See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359057/what-graphs-minimum-vertex-cover-equals-twice-the-maximum-matching) discussion on MathOverflow.